# Show article fields in module

Tags: php, custom-field, fields, pivot

I have two custom fields in my article for longitude and latitude. I'm then trying to build a module to get these two fields from the current article displayed and show in the module.

I have the following but it's not working:

```
<?php
    $id = $item->id;
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query = 'select * from #__fields_values where item_id = "'.$id.'"';
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $fields = $db->loadObjectList();

    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        var_dump($field->value);
    }
?>
```

It's not even showing when using var_dump

Ideally, I'd like to create the variables in the foreach and assign $latitude and $longitude a value (from the article custom field)

Comment: I have several answers to pivot questions ([some that relate to `#__fields_values`](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A12352+fields_values)).  If they don't help, please create a db-fiddle with some sample rows and I'll spin up a query for you.  Out of curiosity, does `$item->id` contain the expected value when you test your script?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is for Joomla 3, you can use the following:

```
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;
use Joomla\CMS\MVC\Model\BaseDatabaseModel;

\JLoader::register('FieldsHelper', JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_fields/helpers/fields.php');
BaseDatabaseModel::addIncludePath(JPATH_SITE . '/components/com_content/models', 'ContentModel');

$model = BaseDatabaseModel::getInstance('Article', 'ContentModel', ['ignore_request' => true]);
$model->setState('params', Factory::getApplication()->getParams());
$fields = FieldsHelper::getFields(
    'com_content.article',
    $model->getItem(Factory::getApplication()->input->get('id')),
    true
);

$array = [];

foreach($fields as $field)
{
    $array[$field->name] = $field->value;
}
```

This will get the current ID, then obtain the fields associated with said ID. It will then create a new array with the name of the field as the key.

If you `var_dump` the array, you will see the following response:

```
Array
(
    [longitude] => 184
    [latitude] => 185
)
```

You can then do whatever you like with the `$array` of fields.

Note, the above code is very basic. You may want to add in some sanity checks to prevent any potential PHP errors. E.g checking if ID actually exists, etc.

Comment: `extract()`? Why do you need separate variables?  I don't endorse the use of "variable variables" -- they usually indicate that an opportunity to use arrays has been missed.

Comment: Thanks! This is showing the array, but how can I then set a variable based on the array strings?

Comment: Have some comments been removed? I don't know who mick ask talking to regarding `extract()`...